# Відповідник до слова "влом", або може є таке слово?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, росіянізм

Наприклад

> Мені влом кудись іти.

Або

> Коли дивлюсь детективи, мені влом пильно стежити за всім що відбувається (деталями).

Так можна казати?

*On a side note, можливо хтось може підказати причину downvote'у? Можливо тому що не показав що намагався сам знайти відповідь? Я шукав на ukrlit.org, goroh.pp.ua і sum.in.ua. І де ще можна пошукати не дуже знаю.*

Comment: Може *ліньки* ?

Comment: @Yola Так, дійсно схоже на відповідник. Але не пам'ятаю щоб чув його вживання. І звучить якось... не сучасно? Ну але це звісно моє суб'єктивне відчуття.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Лінь і ліньки

Обидва ці слова, згідно зі «Словником української мови» у 20 томах, мають потрібне значення (цитую відповідні фрагменти):

- [лінь](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=47920&page=1512)

> *у знач. пред., з інфін., розм*. Не хочеться, нема бажання. *Спати хочеться, а лягати лінь* (С. Васильченко); *Можна розглянути всіх присутніх, але йому* [Серпокрилові] *лінь це робити, і він поводить очима по стелі* (В. Барка); *Ледачий порториканець-кочегар* [пуерториканець-кочегар], *якому лінь було іти і приносити вугілля та дрова, побачив Джалапіту* (Е. Андієвська).

- [лі́ньки](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=47922&page=1512)

> *у знач. пред., з інфін*. Не хочеться, нема бажання; лінь (див. лінь¹ 2). *Йому ліньки було читати самому, і вони читали удвох* (М. Коцюбинський); *Максим .. сидів нерухомо, ліньки було поворухнути й найменшим м'язком* (І. Багряний); *Розмореному Левонтієві було ліньки навіть сердитись* (І. Білик); *Вже й пішки ходити їм ліньки, тротуари їх возять!* (В. Чемерис).

#### Не бере охота, неохота, нехіть

- Слово *неохота* із потрібним значенням [наводить той самий СУМ-20](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=59679&page=1907):

  > *у знач. пред., з інфін*. Не хочеться, немає бажання робити що-небудь. *Гарно ти граєш, та танцювати неохота!* (прислів'я); *— Видно, що тобі неохота розказувати, то й не треба* (М. Чабанівський); *Мені неохота так швидко вертатися додому* (А. Дністровий).
- Хоча СУМ-20 не розглядає окремо вислів *не бере охота*, але там є [охота брала (бере) / взяла](https://sum20ua.com/?wordid=68659&page=2148), та й значення його очевидне з [інших словників](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&highlight=on) і цитат у ГРАК-16, наприклад:

  > Не думай однак, що се я вже так розволочилась, ні, я дуже рада, що я вдома, і тепер мене зовсім не бере охота гнатись на штирі вітри (Леся Українка, лист до М. П. Косача, кінець березня 1891, Колодяжне).
- Хоча СУМ-20 не подає слово *[нехіть](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=60779&page=1942)* як предикатив (присудкове слово, слово категорії стану, станівник), але з цитат у ГРАК-16 очевидно, що його можна так уживати:

  > А як уже незмога або нехіть Вам їхати на чужину, то, може, ліпше, ніж у Криму, було б понад Дністром у Кам'янці, — сей курортик тепер дуже вилюднів, а проте ще не навчився так обдирати людей, як «русская Ривьера»; клімат там гарний, околиця гарна, а народ рідний (Леся Українка, лист до подружжя Грінченків, 29 червня 1909, Телаві).

#### В лом і влом

Деякі словники, наприклад «Російсько-український словник складної лексики» Станіслава Караванського (2012), наводять слово *влом*, але [лише в значенні «вторгнення, злам, злом» (наприклад: *хатній влом*)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC&dicts=30&highlight=on), а не «ліньки, неохота».

Слід зазначити, що в російській мові є два варіанти написання: *в лом* (два слова окремо) і *влом* (одне слово разом). Тому в українській теж розглядатиму обидва ці варіанти.

З 2005 бачу трапляння в «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 16 й у потрібному значенні. Перше — у романі «Зоопарк, або Діти до 16» Андрія Кокотюхи («— Тобі оце не влом із ними калабанитися? — пирхнув один із близнюків»). Оскільки [загалом траплянь небагато](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=phrase&keyword=%5B%D0%B2%D1%83%5D%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%7C%5B%D0%B2%D1%83%5D%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC&sort=%5B%7B%22skey%22%3A%22kw%22%2C%22attr%22%3A%22doc.date%22%2C%22ctx%22%3A%220%22%2C%22bward%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icase%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D&showresults=1), то можу підсумувати їх усі: 1929, 1956, 1963, 1965, 1982, 1989, 1990, 2005 — у значенні «вторгнення, злам, злом»; 2005, 2006×2, 2007×2, 2008, 2010×2 — у значенні «ліньки, неохота»; 2010×3 — знов у значенні «вторгнення, злам, злом»; 2012×3, 2013×3, 2014×7, 2015×5, 2016×4, 2017×6, 2018×3, 2019, 2020, 2022×2 — знов у значенні «ліньки, неохота». Тобто бачимо, що з часом трапляння в потрібному нам значенні все частішають. Та ще й праця [«Молодіжний сленг у постмодерній українській прозі: прагмалінгвістичний аспект» Марії Столяр (2018)](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Stoliar_Mariia/Molodizhnyi_slenh_u_postmodernii_ukrainskii_prozi_prahmalinhvistychnyi_aspekt/) подає *в лом* у потрібному значенні.

Утім, чи варто брати цей росіянізм у свій особистий лексикон — вирішує кожен сам для саме.

#### Фразеологізми

- мене баглаї/ліньки беруть/обсіли/обсідають (з [колекції словників R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8&highlight=on));
- мені баглаї/ліньки вкинулися (звідти ж);
- на мене баглаї/ліньки напали (звідти ж).

Хоча зазвичай їх використовують для характеристики загального стану, але, якщо Вашою метою є врізноманітнити мову, то, мені здається, можна спробувати сказати щось на зразок «мене баглаї обсіли писати цей документ».